# Per-app language preferences - get list of app's available language programmatically?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-xml, android-resources

So based on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#kotlin

we can use

```
android {
  androidResources {
    generateLocaleConfig = true
  }
}
```

which automatically generates language list available for for users to change for a specific app:

[image]

(all languages list)

This list available for Android 13+ and only in app's system settings.

I want to implement a picker inside the app.

How can I get the same languages list without manually implementing it?

How to access the list which `android.androidResources.generateLocaleConfig` feature generated?

**Update**

I tried

```
val localeManager = context
    .getSystemService(LocaleManager::class.java)
localeManager.overrideLocaleConfig?.supportedLocales?.let { localeList ->
    Timber.d("localeList ${localeList.size()}")
}
```

but it's empty and works only for Android 13+

`LocaleManagerCompat` doesn't have such method